# Show that $f$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

Let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a function which maps intervals to intervals .Suppose for each sequence $x_n$ converging to $x$ there exists a constant $M$ such that $$\lvert f(x_n)-f(x)\rvert\le M\sup_{n,m}\lvert f(x_n)-f(x_m)\rvert$$

Show that $f$ is continuous at $x$.

**My try**:

Let $x_n\to x$. To show that $f(x_n)\to f(x)$. Since $x_n\to x$ so for any $\delta>0 $ we have $x_n\in (x-\delta,x+\delta)$ for all $n>N_\delta$ for some $N_\delta$.

Since $f$ maps intervals to intervals then 
$$f(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subseteq(f(x)-\epsilon,f(x)+\epsilon )\,\, \text{for some}\,\, \epsilon>0$$

So $f(x_n)\in (f(x)-\epsilon,f(x)+\epsilon )$ for all $n>N_\delta$.

Corresponding to $x_n$  there exists a constant $M$ such that $$|f(x_n)-f(x)|\le M\sup_{n,m}|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|\le M(2\epsilon).$$

Thus

$$\lvert f(x_n)-f(x)\rvert\le 2M\epsilon$$

If I can make $\epsilon\to 0$ then I think we are done. But I am failing to do so.

Comment: Hint : choose a subsequence of $(f(x_n))$ that converges.

Comment: I'm being a bit pedantic here but I don't think you can claim $$f((x-\delta, x+\delta)) = (f(x) - \epsilon, f(x) + \epsilon)$$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. We don't know that it maps  $(x-\delta, x+\delta)$ to an interval centered at $f(x)$. However, it is certainly true that $$f((x-\delta, x+\delta)) \subseteq (f(x) - \epsilon, f(x) + \epsilon)$$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, which is good enough. I dont see any other problems with the proof. Nice job!

Comment: @CaptainLama; If $f(x_{n_k})$ converges then that does not mean that $f(x_n)$ converges

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is almost finished. All you have to do is take a subsequence that converges and for that subsequence $\varepsilon\to 0$

Comment: Then my justification will go like : since every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence so $f(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence say $f(x_{n_k})$ which converges say to some $p$.

Comment: Now the corresponding sequence $x_{n_k}\to x$ then by hypothesis  for some M $|f(x_{n_k})-f(x)|\le M\sup _{n_k,m_k} |f(x_{n_k})-f(x_{m_k})|<2M\epsilon $ forall  $\epsilon>0\implies f(x_{n_k})\to f(x)$

Comment: But we have to prove that $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ we have only proved $f(x_{n_k})\to f(x)$. How to fix this ?

Comment: You correctly showed that for any convergent subsequence of $f(x_n)$, the limit must be $f(x)$. Now it is a basic result that if all convergent subsequences of a bounded sequence have the same limit, then the sequence converges to that limit. If you have not seen this yet, I urge you to prove it (it's quite easy).